# Unable to create mysql database python ("can't connect to server localhost")

Tags: python, mysql

I am simply following this example https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_create_db.asp

using this code

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="yourusername",
  passwd="yourpassword"
)
```

I leave localhost unchanged, but set the user/pass to be my personal user/password I use to log into the computer. I am getting

```
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (61)
```

but am surprised to find no clear explanation as to why online. It seems like such a simple line of code... I don't know what I'm doing wrong. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should give proper keyword including database

```
mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='password',
                              host='127.0.0.1',
                              database='db_name')
```